# Looking for a model or description of an EME channel

Tags: propagation, frequency, eme

I am looking for any technical/scientifical/specialized reference describing in some detail the moonbounce for VHF/low UHF frequencies.

More precisely, I would be interested in a paper or publication describing some aspects such as the dispersion time, dispersion bandwidth, whether the signal follows a Rayleigh or Rice distribution, the type of fading and so on; and, if possible, how they vary with the frequency in use.

These aspects must have been already studied, but I was not able to find any technical documentation describing them. If anyone here could provide any reference, it would be great!

Thanks in advance.

73 de EA1FID

Comment: Bob Larkin describes DSP signal averaging and filtering moonbounce signals in Chapt.12.5 of *Experimental Methods in RF Design*. He also points to *the ARRL UHF/Microwave Experimenters Manual* ARRL, 1990, Chapter 10

Comment: Search for *planetary radar* not just amateur moonbounce/EME. There were publications in the 60s about the time delay spectrum of the moon and some planets, at different frequencies, and what that meant for surface flatness, conductivity etc. Done from Goldstone, Arecibo and others.

Comment: @glen_geek That would make a good answer.

Comment: Maybe you could find a ham who does EME work who would be willing to work with you to provide experimental data?

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://www.qsl.net/ik3xtv/ARCHIVIO/Reirradiation%20properties%20of%20the%20lunar%20surface.pdf), published in 2011 by Flavio Egano (IK3XTV), references an old NASA lunar radar study published in 1973 that might be helpful.  Unfortunately the paper does not seem to be available in electronic format.

There appears to be an [even older paper published in the form of a progress report in 1966 by MIT Lincoln Laboratory](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19670002742), but the wavelengths were quite short.  Another paper that might be helpful is [this 1980 USGS survey paper](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1046b/report.pdf).  I found some other possible resources [here on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=radar%20studies%20of%20the%20moon%20NASA%201973&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS984US985&oq=radar%20studies%20of%20the%20moon%20NASA%201973).

It also seems that Mr. Egano published a book on amateur radio propagation, including EME.  It is [available from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09247XRVW) in paperback for $15 (at this writing) as well as in Kindle format.

I don't know if any of these will answer your need directly, but they seem like good places to start to build a model.